# How to Import Data to Android Emulator (and Edit It, ultimately to share a virtual copy of my phone)?

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to take an Android phone and import all of its apps and their data into an Android emulator (i.e. Tinder, Gmail, Texts, etc). I know that you can import files into Android Studio, but I also want to take this 'virtual phone' of mine and be able to download the entire emulator instance and share it with others (i.e I don't want the emulator to have to, for instance, connect to the Gmail server in order to populate the email data on the phone).

If I could also edit some of the data (such as changing the email addresses) that would also be great.

Is this possible within Android Studio or other available emulators?

I read other questions on Stack Overflow and looked into Android Studio documentation, and it's unclear if all the features I want are available.

Comment: You realize that would be a massive copyright violation, right?  You don't have those company's permission to distribute their apps by sharing an emulator with them on it.

Comment: Also, Android Studio isn't an emulator, it's an IDE that comes with an emulator.  That emulator writes all the files for the emulated environment to your hard drive.  So all you need to do to share an emulator is share those files.

Comment: How would it be a copyright violation if I'm basically showing people what's on my phone? And I don't want anyone to be able to 'play' with the apps, just view the data.

Comment: By distibuting the emulator image, you're distributing a copy of the apps.  That's making a copy, which violates copyright law.  If you were "showing them what's on your phone" with a screenshot you'd be ok.  Giving them a copy of the apps is what's the problem.